# Why do we need TxOutRef in addition to TxOut?

Tags: plutus

I'm sorry if it feels like an odd question.

In `Plutus.V1.Ledger.Contexts` module I see that `TxOut` is a transaction output and `TxOutRef` is a reference to a transaction output.

In code, we use it often to

- check some statements about txInputs
- to describe a transaction's constrains

But what was the reason behind the introduction of this abstraction? What would be a correct analogy?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `TxOut` cannot be used to uniquely identify an UTxO, as it is just an address and a value.

`TxOutRef` is unique as it is the transaction id and the output index within that transaction.